# How come this React.useState returned setter function does not save the state

Tags: reactjs

OK, this should not happen. tableTypes below is not set?

```
// At the top of a functional component:
const [tableTypes,setTableTypes] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
...

// Inside some event handler function:
const types = ...
setTableTypes(types)
setConsoleMessage(JSON.stringify([tableTypes, types]))

// In the React element hierarchy I have the consoleMessage.
// In the rendered UI, I can see the nonempty array 'types',
// but tableTypes is still empty.
{consoleMessage}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: It does set it, but *next* time the component is rendered. tableTypes isn't actually being assigned to, why expect its value to change?

Comment: @johnrsharpe: Does not setting a state variable force the component to be rendered?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't stop function execution midway through.